# FormatException when parsing BigInteger

Tags: c#, parsing, sum, biginteger

I try to solve a problem at codewars.com where I add two BitInteger. 
[Here is the Link](http://www.codewars.com/kata/5324945e2ece5e1f32000370/train/csharp)

With my code:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Globalization;

public static class Kata
{
    public static string sumStrings(string a, string b)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b);
      BigInteger numbera = BigInteger.Parse(a);
      BigInteger numberb = BigInteger.Parse(b);
      BigInteger numberc;

      numberc = numbera + numberb;
      Console.WriteLine(numberc);
      return numberc.ToString();
    }
}
```

I get an FormatException-Error:

```
System.FormatException : The value could not be parsed. 
at System.Numerics.BigNumber.ParseBigInteger (System.String value, NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Kata.sumStrings (System.String a, System.String b) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at CodeWarsTest.Test6 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

but the output seems to be correct.

```
input: string 1 --> "712569312664357328695151392" 
input: string 2 --> "8100824045303269669937"
output: sum --> 712577413488402631964821329
```

Why do I get a FormatException here??

EDIT: The code works in MonoDevelopment but not on the Codewars.com-site.

Comment: @Henk Can you please visit the link and run the code there? Thank you!

Comment: I didn't get any exception on parsing lines. What is your environments by the way?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem at Codewars.com !?!?!

Comment: When I run the code in MonoDevelop I also don't get any error. :/

Comment: But I didn't know if the error comes from my code or from the compiling.

Comment: No problem with the code but with the compiler

Comment: @Henk: and certainly not an external link that requires you to sign in or sign up.

Comment: @Rudy But Codewars is the second best page on the WWW after SO. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a problem with their site. One of the tests passes you an invalid input (an empty string) for the first parameter.

Here is the code that catches this problem:

```
BigInteger na, nb;
if (!BigInteger.TryParse(a, out na)) {
    Console.WriteLine("A is invalid: '{0}'",a);
}
if (!BigInteger.TryParse(b, out nb)) {
    Console.WriteLine("B is invalid: '{0}'", b);
}
var nc = na + nb;
return nc.ToString();
```

It prints

```
A is invalid: ''
```

for test number 5.